# Unable to install picom

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, aur, picom

I am trying to install picom on Manjaro. I tried to download it from the AUR `yay -S picom-git` am getting these errors

```
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/libconfig-1.7.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: ninja: signature from "Anatol Pomozov (Arch Linux developer account) <anatolik@archlinux.org>" is invalid
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/ninja-1.11.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: docbook-xml: signature from "Felix Yan <felixonmars@archlinux.org>" is invalid
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/docbook-xml-4.5-9-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: asciidoc: signature from "Caleb Maclennan <alerque@archlinux.org>" is invalid
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/asciidoc-10.2.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: uthash: signature from "Santiago Torres-Arias <santiago@archlinux.org>" is invalid
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/uthash-2.3.0-1-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
error: target not found: ninja
error: target not found: meson
error: target not found: docbook-xml
error: target not found: docbook-xsl
error: target not found: asciidoc
error: target not found: uthash
 -> error installing repo packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo pacman -Syy` and retry your command. If that doesn't work, try `sudo pacman -Scc`.